# Batch file to move .txt files from one folder to another in a specific time interval keeping a check on the size

Tags: batch-file

I have Windows XP installed on my computer.

I have a folder named "Bob1" in C drive in which there are 7 files.

I need to move (cut-paste) them into a folder named "Bob2" (which is also in C drive)every evening  between 6PM-9PM (not before 6 PM and not after 9 PM ) if the following 2 conditions hold true :

1: The no. of files in folder Bob1 with .txt extention are exactly equal to 7.

2: None of these 7 files should have a size equal to 0.

3: None of these 7 files should have a size greater than or equal to 1 MB.

Comment: You have listed a set of requirements (well written, much better than most). But you have not asked a programming question.

Comment: I tried to search for the answers to this problem in particular...could not find it...so put this up here.That is it and it has helped.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.  Use task scheduler to run it every minute between 6 pm and 9 pm

```
@echo off
pushd "c:\bob1"
   for %%a in (*.txt) if %%~za EQU 0 goto :EOF
   dir *.txt /b |find /c /v "" |findstr "^7$" >nul && for %%a in (*.txt) move "%%a" "C:\bob2"
popd
```

Comment: I have added a 3rd point in the set of conditions that need to hold true."None of these 7 files should have a size greater than or equal to 1 MB." Can someone now answer my querry....??